# Fibonacci numbers- input

Tags: java

On this program, how do i keep asking the user if he/she wants to find another number? It only works once. Should I use a while loop? How to set that up? I am confused. Thanks.

```
public class FibonacciNUmbers
{

public static int calcFibNum(int x)
{
 if (x == 0)
   return 0;
 else if (x == 1)
   return 1;
 else
   return calcFibNum(x-1) + calcFibNum(x-2);
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
  int x = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("The " + x + "th Fibonacci number of " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));

  String answer = "Y"; 
  while (answer.equals("Y"))
  {
     System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonaci number of another number?(Y/N)");
     answer = in.next(); //declare your variable answer outside the loop so you  can use it in the evaluation of how many times to do the loop.
  if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
  {
   System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
   x = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
  }
  else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
     System.out.println();

  }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make use of `continue` and `break`. Try this:

```
while (answer.equals("Y"))
  {
     System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonaci number of another number?(Y/N)");
     answer = in.next(); //declare your variable answer outside the loop so you  can use it in the evaluation of how many times to do the loop.
  if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
  {
   System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
   x = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
   continue; // continue your loop without executing any further statements
  }
  else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
     System.out.println();
     break ; // break the loop and 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of program flow suggests the use of the `do { ... } while();` syntax. You want it to iterate once, and then keep going while the user answers 'Y' to your question.

```
int x;
String answer;
do{
    System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
    x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
    System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonaci number of another number?(Y/N)");
    answer = in.next();
} while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
System.out.println();
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that your code has a small bug - in your `calcFibNum(x)` method, you do not check any input and so a negative number will recurse infinitely until you run out of stack space.